# I want req.body.date to show only date instead of time and time zone

Tags: node.js, nodes, ejs

I am an absolute beginner in Nodejs and I am creating a crud base schedule app to display user made schedule with date.
I want to display only the date but req.body.date displaying complete date with time zone and current time. Please help me with this.

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JUDj.png)

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    TodoTask.find({}, (err,tasks)=>{
        res.render('index.ejs', {todoTask : tasks});
    });

});


app.post('/', async(req, res)=>{
    const todoTask = new TodoTask({
        content : req.body.content,
        date: req.body.date,
    });

    try{
    await  todoTask.save();
        res.redirect('/');
    }
    catch(err){
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please paste your code into your question instead of linking to an image.

Answer (score 1):

i am using this may be this will help you https://momentjs.com/

```
npm install moment

const dateFormat = require('moment')

moment(date).format('DD/MMM/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to the one below, you'll get your date in the `Wed Oct 07 2020`, but you have a couple of formats outlined on [Mozilla web doc (Date)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). This does not require any extra npm package. As long as the `req.body.date` is a valid, then you good, otherwise you'll get `Invalid Date`.

```
app.post('/', async(req, res)=>{
    let date = new Date(req.body.date);
    const todoTask = new TodoTask({
        content : req.body.content,
        date: date.toDateString()
    });

    try{
    await  todoTask.save();
        res.redirect('/');
    }
    catch(err){
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```